# How to use a for-loop to go through the lines in a txt file Java

Tags: java, for-loop, http-post

Basically what I am trying to do is make something in java that will send POST requests to a website, but with a different token each time. I have a file full of these "tokens" called tokens.txt and I want it to loop through these for each request so that it sends a request for each token. I have done something like this in the past in python:

```
link = "https://example.com"
joined = 0
failed = 0
with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:
    tokens = f.read().splitlines()
    for token in tokens:
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
                   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11",
                   "Authorization" : token}

        response = post(link, headers=headers).status_code
        if response > 199 and response < 300:
            joined += 1

        else:
            failed += 1
```

As you can see in the python code, It loops through the file changing the token variable and sending the request

However, I am fairly new to java so I don't know what I am doing and I am confused.

Comment: @Aniox It's the reference to the file: `with open("tokens.txt", "r") as f:`

Comment: It isn't; it's Python.

Comment: @Aniox: OP clearly says it's Python, but they want to know how to read a file line by line in Java, just like they know how to do it in Python.

Comment: in [this article](https://stackabuse.com/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-java/) explains how to iterate over lines in a document. [Here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-java) are some ways to make a request in java.

Comment: How don't you??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use a for-loop try this:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int joined = 0, failed = 0;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
            Path path = Paths.get("tokens.txt");
            List<String> tokens = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            for (String token : tokens) {
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);

                int response = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (response > 199 && response < 300)
                    joined++;
                else
                    failed++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```